# SNMP - Decode Hex String Value

Tags: snmp, pysnmp

This is my first question here, so hope it's correctly done.

Im trying to get some information from a ZTE C300 OLT.
The thing is when i try to get the SN of one of the ONTS I get the response in HEX-String

```
snmpwalk -cpublic -v2c [OLTIP] 1.3.6.1.4.1.3902.1082.500.10.2.2.5.1.2
```

And this is the response that I get

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.3902.1082.500.10.2.2.5.1.2.285278736.1 = Hex-STRING: 5A 54 45 47 C8 79 9B 27
```

This is the SN that i have on the OLT ZTEGC8799B27, but im trying to convert the HEX-STRING into text and i don't get that SN text.

Indeed i have a python script for SNMP and the response that i get for that OID is

```
{'1.3.6.1.4.1.3902.1082.500.10.2.2.5.1.2.285278736.1': "ZTEGÈy\x9b'"}
```

Can someone give me a hand on this?. I'm new on SNMP and this is giving me some headache.
Thanks in advace!

Comment: Only the vendor MIB document can explain what is stored in that management object and how to interpret the value. It is impossible for others to guess the meaning.

Comment: Lex, Thanks so much for the information. Indeed it was easier. The firts 4 bytes were encoded, and the other 4 is the actual serial number splitted every 2 digits. So i only need to decode the first part and concatenate the rest. Thanks for the answer man!

Comment: You should post you own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it was easier. The firts 4 bytes were encoded, and the other 4 is the actual serial number splitted every 2 digits. So i only need to decode the first part and concatenate the rest.

Answer (score 0):

This is a 8 octet hex string, the first 4 octets are ASCII.
Just convert hex 2 ascii.

Comment: Do not convert my string to a real number.

Answer (score 0):

Works with OLT ZTE C320

```py
def hex_str(str):
    
    str = str.strip()
    str = str.split(' ')

    vendor_id = ''
    serial = str[4:]
    serial = "".join(serial)

    for hex_byte in str[:4]:
        vendor_id += chr(int(hex_byte, 16))
        
    normalized_serial = vendor_id + serial

    return normalized_serial


def ascii_to_hex(str):

    arr = []
    hex_byte = ''
    
    for i in range(len(str)):
        hex_byte += hex(ord(str[i]))
        
    hex_byte = hex_byte.replace('0x', ' ')
    hex_byte = hex_str(hex_byte)
    
    return hex_byte
    

# value = f"5A 54 45 47 C8 79 9B 27 "
# value = f"49 54 42 53 8B 69 A2 45 "
# value = f"ZTEGÈy\x9b'"
value = f"ITBS2Lz/"
# value = f"ITBS2HP#"

if(len(value) == 24):
    print(hex_str(value))
else:
    print(ascii_to_hex(value))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).